# Cross app key sharing with Akavache Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, single-sign-on, akavache

I have implemented the Akavache to work with my Xamarin.Android app. The saving and retrieval of keys work fine. I wanted to achieve a single sign on experience over two of my apps. I wanted to know if there is a way I can share the keys saved from one of my apps to the other app.

Some code I use for Key saving and retrieval.

```
BlobCache.ApplicationName = "IIMSuite";

 await BlobCache.Secure.InsertObject("Token", authResult.Token);
 await BlobCache.Secure.InsertObject("SavedUserEmail", userName);
 await BlobCache.Secure.InsertObject("SavedUserName", userEmail);

 try
            {

 userName = await BlobCache.Secure.GetObject<string>("SavedUserName");
 userEmail = await BlobCache.Secure.GetObject<string>("SavedUserEmail");
 token = await BlobCache.Secure.GetObject<string>("Token");

}
catch(KeyNotFoundException ex){}
```

I tried implementing the same code in the other app by keeping the `BlobCache.ApplicationName` consistent but that does not seem to work and does not retrieve any values.

Any help is appreciated.